# Не удается создать и подключиться к базе с помощью firebirdsql

Tags: python, firebird, база-данных, sql

[[@rnd_d](/users/672/rnd_d)](/users/672/rnd_d), действую согласно принципу упрощения я написал программу

```
import pyodbc
#import kinterbasdb
import firebirdsql
import os
import json,sqlite3,sql
s1='''
create table CLIENTS
    (
       ID    INTEGER NOT NULL,
       COMPANY   VARCHAR(50),
       "LAST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
       "FIRST NAME"   VARCHAR(50),
       "E-MAIL ADDRESS"   VARCHAR(50),
       "JOB TITLE"   VARCHAR(50),
       "BUSINESS PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
       "HOME PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
       "MOBILE PHONE"   VARCHAR(25),
       "FAX NUMBER"   VARCHAR(25),
       ADDRESS   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
       CITY   VARCHAR(50),
       "STATE/PROVINCE"   VARCHAR(50),
       "ZIP/POSTAL CODE"   VARCHAR(15),
       "COUNTRY/REGION"   VARCHAR(50),
       "WEB-SITE"   VARCHAR(25),
       NOTES   BLOB SUB_TYPE 1,
       INCLUDING   BLOB,
       CONSTRAINT PK_CLIENTS_ID PRIMARY KEY(ID)
    );
'''
s2='''create ascending index IDX_CLIENTS_CITY on CLIENTS (CITY);'''
#os.remove('D:/ThirdTask/test1.fdb')
conn=firebirdsql.create_database(dsn='localhost/3050:/test.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
cur=conn.cursor()
cur.execute(s1)
cur.execute(s2)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

где s1 оно выполнило, а s2 выполнить не сумело в прошлой программе. И в результате оно не создало в текущей папке файл test1.fdb, т. е. даже не удалось создать базу.

Comment: А что если?

cur.execute(s1)
conn.commit()
cur.execute(s2)
conn.commit()

Comment: @rnd_d именно при 2 коммитах возникает ошибка, указанная на http://hashcode.ru/questions/151832/python-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-attributeerror-transaction-instance-has-no-attribute-trans_handle см. ответ на http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781696/error-attributeerror-transaction-instance-has-no-attribute-trans-handle. После одного коммита на все строки эта ошибк действительно исчезла, но почему то не создается база.

Comment: а если закомментировать строчку cur.execute(s2) база создается?

Comment: @rnd_d, не создается.

Comment: @rnd_d , я обнаружил, что при использовании строки подключения
    conn=firebirdsql.create_database(host='localhost', database='D:/boreas.fdb', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')
база создается. А в самой текущей папке D:\ThirdTask я увидел атрибут только для чтения, который пытался снять, но не получилось (при открывании свойств снова квадратик был залитым)